# Suitable word or phrase to replace 'unique' when something is almost unique?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have this sentence as part of an abstract

> Verification of space weather forecasts presents some unique challenges compared with other types of forecasts.

I go on to detail briefly what those challenges are. Now, these aspects aren't, in truth, entirely unique to this area, but are still much more of a factor than in other areas. I am trying to succinctly replace 'unique' with something more suitable.

I have toyed with 'peculiar' or 'idiosyncratic' but neither really appeals. 'Particular' might fit but I'm still not too happy with that.

Unique works because in the context because I think it also conveys a sense of these challenges being interesting, which doesn't come across so much with the other words mentioned.

Comment: .......unusual!

Comment: If you want to be "truthful", you can't use *unique*, so you could settle on Edwin's *unusual*. Or recast to something like *presents some challenges **not often encountered** with other types of forecasts*. But the whole question is really a matter of "creative writing advice", rather than a (not particularly welcome) single-word-request for a term meaning *not quite unique, but nevertheless uncommon and therefore interesting*.

Comment: Why do you need to modify _challenges_ with anything? "...presents some challenges compared with other types of forecasts" is sufficient to convey the message that "Verifying [_Verification of_ is verbose] space weather forecasts is different from verifying other types of forecasts". Being _unique_ isn't a sufficient condition for being _interesting_: it may be a necessary condition, however. _Verifying space weather forecasts is more challenging than verifying other types of forecasts_ seems to me to convey all that needs to be said. The challenges--the hook--will be listed in the text.

Comment: It presents some *intrinsic* challenges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe *novel* captures some of the meaning you're trying to convey? It suggests something out of the ordinary and interesting.

> Verification of space weather forecasts presents novel challenges when compared with other types of forecasts.

Answer (score 3):

"Extraordinary", "uncommon", "incomparable". "Rare" might also work here.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that it presents some [*particular*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/particular) challenges:

> **particular**
>   2. Separate and distinct from others of the same group, category, or nature: *made an exception in this particular case*.
>   3. Worthy of note; exceptional: *a piano performance of particular depth and fluidity*.

Answer (score -1):

Check the Merriam Webster definition. It seems there are multiple meanings for “unique.” It covers the gauntlet, from “unique” (one of a kind; like no other) to lower levels of uniqueness (on a scale from more unique to less unique): “Sole,” “unequaled,” “peculiar,” “distinct,” and “unusual.” Check the thesaurus for more. Is this the evolution of the English language, or a bastardization of the word through misuse by the masses? Webster even wrote a short paper below the definitions discussing this.